# How do I get Š into my JSON?

Tags: php, json

I have the following code:

```
Header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
Header('Content-type: application/json');
$aData['test'] = html_entity_decode("&#x160;");
echo json_encode($aData);
```

I want it to output Š, but instead it outputs:

```
{
    test: "&#x160;"
}
```

On my local Xampp server it works fine, but on the real server not, could it some kind of setting or is there another solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably due to your PHP version on local & server differing. Prior to PHP 5.4, the default encoding for `html_entity_decode` was `ISO-8859-1` but you want `UTF-8`.

Two solutions here:

1. Upgrade PHP to 5.4 or newer; OR
2. Explicitly declare the encoding: `html_entity_decode("&#x160;", ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401, "UTF-8")`

[Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php).